Mathematics and calmness
I wanted to ask if in order for someone to be a good mathematician they need to enjoy a relationship, with someone, such as a teacher or a companion, that has a calming effect on them.
Thank you.

In secondary school, I was the best at mathematics of the entire class and I was a loner :-)

I wonder if adding something about why you ask would get you better answers.
My personal answer is no, not at all.

Everybody, probably needs a relations with something that has a calming effect. As, effectively by force everyone will have a relationship with something that stresses them, if no counterforce exists- their stress will be unbounded!

The main missing context here is the age of OP. That said, I will give my 2 cents. I would say that for most people, being calmer is probably a good thing that will have a positive impact on most areas of your life. I believe although I am not sure, that studies do show that having a partner makes someone calmer overall. If this is the case, then the answer is probably yes in general. However, I don't think it's a good idea for someone who is single to pursue getting a partner/getting into a relationship just so that their maths gets better. That's not going to work out well for anyone.

I don't think another person is necessary (though it may be helpful).
But I would say that in order for someone to be a good mathematician, their relationship with mathematics itself has to have a calming effect on them.
And even more generally:

In order for someone to be a good performer of X, their relationship with the performance of X has to have a calming effect on them.

I would also suggest that "calming" might not be the right word to use here (but I know what you're trying to say). It feels overly restrictive to the point of excluding what a professional athlete might feel before a game, some kind of simultaneous calm/excitement. Maybe some phrase like "at home" would convey that better.

In order for someone to be a good performance of X, they need to feel "at home" while performing X.

